# PHP - Salvar arquivo PDF temporariamente

Tags: php, phpmailer

O sistema que estou desenvolvendo gera arquivos PDF e armazena em uma pasta para ser enviado por e-mail. É possível salvar esse arquivo temporariamente enquanto é anexado e o e-mail é enviado? Se sim, como?

Comment: Daniel Neto te recomendo a fazer o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como funciona a comunidade, primeiramente tente fazer algo, depois faça a pergunta expondo sua dúvida e ou problema.

Comment: Utilize o retorno da função responsável por enviar, caso o retorno seja `true`, é sinal que o arquivo já foi enviado e que você já pode apaga-lo.

Comment: Isso resolve meu problema, valeu.